# Unable to turn off eslint no-unused-expressions

Tags: eslint, create-react-app, flowtype, type-assertion

I have created an app with create-react-app and I have applied the airbnb rules. The app also contains redux and flow.

The following code is throwing the no-unused-expressions error in eslint:

```
const reducer = (state: string = '', action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // cases
        default:
            (action: empty); // this is throwing eslint/no-unused-expressions
            return state;
    }
};
```

I am trying to switch off the rule in eslintrc in order to replace it with flowtype/no-unused-expressions

content of my .eslintrc.yml

```
extends:
    - airbnb
parser: babel-eslint
env:
    browser: true
    jest: true
globals:
    SyntheticEvent: true,
rules:
    no-unused-expressions: off
    react/prefer-stateless-function: off
    react/jsx-filename-extension: off
    react/jsx-one-expression-per-line: off
```

With this settings, the no-unused-expressions error is not shown anymore in the editor (vscode). However as soon as I compile with `npm run start` the error is still there:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

causing it to fail to compile.

Of course if I disable locally eslint for that rule for example with

```
// eslint-disable-line no-unused-expressions
```

Everything is working in both the editor and the browser. However, as I said I am trying to replace the eslint rule with the flowtype one exactly to avoid to be obliged to disable eslint every time I am using a flow type assertion.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

package.json content:

```
{
  "name": "would-you-rather",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-flowtype-essential": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.2.0",
    "flow-bin": "0.89.0",
    "flow-typed": "2.5.1",
    "immutable": "4.0.0-rc.12",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "16.6.3",
    "react-icons": "3.2.2",
    "react-redux": "6.0.0",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-immutable": "4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0", 
    "semantic-ui-css": "2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "0.84.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "docdash": "1.0.1",
    "jsdoc": "3.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "jsdoc": "jsdoc --configure jsdoc.conf.json --recurse --private",
    "flow": "$(npm bin)/flow",
    "flow-typed": "$(npm bin)/flow-typed",
    "postinstall": "$(npm bin)/flow-typed install"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

[Link of the project on github](https://github.com/luca-borrione/reactnd-project2-wouldyourather/tree/submitted) if you want to play with it

Comment: I'm really curious as to the purpose of that `(action: empty)` line. It does appear to be an unused expression. That cast will not change the type of subsequent references to `action` in that block. And it should not be possible to cast the type of a variable to `empty`. Are you trying to force a type error in the `default` case?

Comment: @JesseHallett Hey, thanks for asking. Using the empty type assertion in the default case validates that every single type of action have been handled as per [flow documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/#toc-typing-redux-reducers). There's a [flowtype no-unused-expressions rule](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype/blob/master/.README/rules/no-unused-expressions.md) which ignores type assertion but my understanding is that it requires to switch off the eslint no-unused-expressions rule first, in order to replace it. And I seem unable to switch the latter off.

Comment: Can you please show your package.json (specifically the scripts section)? It seems that somehow, ESLint is run differently during `npm run start` vs in your editor.

Comment: @LucaBorrione Oh neat! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I added the content of my package.json to my question

Answer (score 2):

The scripts included with react-scripts specifically do not read overrides from eslintrc files. The reasoning is explained in an [issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/808#issuecomment-252928970):

> I don't think it would be a good solution. We aggressively show lint violations (in browser for errors, in console for warnings), and so we didn't include any style rules in the config.
>
> I think style rules should be handled completely separately, before you commit. They shouldn't distract you during development or be loud in browser or terminal.

I think the idea is that you are free to use your own eslint configuration to add style rules specific to your project that you check during development; but the `build` and `start` will not look at it, and will stick to the conservative rule set bundled with react-scripts instead. The fact that you have found a case where those conservative rules interfere with your workflow probably deserves an issue report with create-react-app.

I think that the easiest solution is to use the `// eslint-disable-line no-unused-expressions` line, as you mentioned. But there are a couple of other options. You can modify the expression to convince eslint that it is not unused, or you can use a tool like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to modify react-scripts' Webpack configuration so that it reads your custom eslint configuration.

### Convince eslint that the expression is used

The eslint configuration that react-scripts uses is in `node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/index.js`. You can see that it sets some exceptions to the no-unused-expressions rule:

```
'no-unused-expressions': [
  'error',
  {
    allowShortCircuit: true,
    allowTernary: true,
    allowTaggedTemplates: true,
  },
],
```

Ternary expressions are allowed. You can combine the type assertion with a function call (which should never run because `action` should always be truthy):

```
(action: empty) || noop();
```

### Patch react-scripts' Webpack configuration

You can see the code that react-scripts uses to run eslint in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js` and again in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js`:

```
// First, run the linter.
// It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
{
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  use: [
    {
      options: {
        formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
        eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
        // @remove-on-eject-begin
        baseConfig: {
          extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
          settings: { react: { version: '999.999.999' } },
        },
        ignore: false,
        useEslintrc: false,
        // @remove-on-eject-end
      },
      loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
    },
  ],
  include: paths.appSrc,
},
```

To use your custom configuration you need to change the line `useEslintrc: false` to `useEslintrc: true` in both files. Then use patch-package to automatically reapply that change whenever react-scripts is installed or updated. Add this script to the scripts section in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepare": "patch-package"
}
```

Install patch-package, and postinstall-prepare to make sure that yarn runs the that `prepare` script:

```
$ yarn add --dev patch-package postinstall-prepare
```

After editing the Webpack configuration files run this command to save a patch (note that the yarn commands above will have reverted your changes, so make the same changes again before running this step):

```
$ yarn patch-package react-scripts
```

That will create a file with a name like `patches/react-scripts+2.1.1.patch`. You should check this file into version control.

Comment: Hey thanks for your big effort! I saw the discussion on the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/808#issuecomment-252928970) you mentioned today as well before reading your answer and I am a little bit surprised about this decision honestly. I raised an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6121) in create-react-app let's see if anyone will suggest something

Comment: I tried both your suggestions but 1. (action: empty) || noop(); still throws the same error (I checked node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/index.js and it's the same you posted) 2. I followed your instructions but when I ran yarn patch-package react-scripts it failed with error Error: Unable to find a flow project in the current dir or any of it's parent dirs! Please run this command from within a Flow project. which is strange as I do have a .flowconfig file.

Comment: @LucaBorrione That Flow error is strange. Do you have a script in package.json that runs Flow when packages are installed? Perhaps a postinstall, or a prepare script? If so you might try temporarily disabling it while you create the patch. And are you using create-react-app v2 or v1?

Comment: Yep, you were right: I temporarily disabled the postinstall script, generated the patch, enabled again the postinstall script, removed the node_modules folder and ran npm install again .. it applied the patch and everything is now working! However I strongly believe that this should be done by CRA directly just switching useEslintrc to true in order to allow to load a custom eslintrc instead of obliging us to patch it. I really can't see the reason why they want to impose their styling rules.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesse pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030217/1032370) it looks like ignoring .eslintrc is something done intentionally by the react scripts. 
I have been able to achieve my goal by ejecting and removing the eslintConfig section added by the reject script to the package.json .. however I feel that it would be better to disable eslint inline and avoid ejecting

Answer (score 0):

#### This resolved it for me for `react-scripts:4.0.1`

1. Remove the `eslintConfig` from your **`package.json`** file.
   It should be under your `scripts` key value.
2. Now, just add an **.eslintrc.js** in the root of your project with this configuration in it:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: ["react-app", "react-app/jest"],
  overrides: [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.js?(x)"],
      "rules": {
          "no-unused-vars": [1, { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*You can also do `"no-unused-vars": [0]` which will turn off linting for unused vars*

3. After adding this, you can restart your server.
   *react-scripts* will detect that you have an `.eslintrc` file in the root of your project and will override the defaults with those in that file.